# Qual è la differenza tra "tanto quanto" e "quanto"?

Tags: grammar

Dal mio punto di vista le differenze sono queste:

"Quanto" sta a indicare un insieme specifico e
sostituisce "tutti quelli che/quello quello che".

Esempi:

1) Ordina quante pizze vuoi = ordina tutte le pizze che vuoi.

2) Prendi quanti soldi ci sono sul tavolo = prendi tutti i soldi che hai sul tavolo.

Qui non potrei dire "mangio tante quante pizze mangi tu", ma solo senza "tanto".

"Tanto quanto" invece mi sa più di "nella stessa e identica quantità di/che.

Esempi:

1) Guadagna tanti soldi quante le calorie che assume.

2) Verso tante lacrime quante disgrazie vedo.

Qui non posso dire per esempio "voglio soldi quanti privilegi" ma "voglio tanti soldi quanti privilegi".

"Tanto quanto" è parecchio comparativo di per sé e ha la precisa funzione di assumere valore comparativo e mettere in relazione due cose, "quanto" invece no.

C'è da dire che anche QUANTO (non necessariamente accompagnato da TANTO) A VOLTE assume valore comparativo.

3) Sei intelligente quanto è stupida una scimmia = sei tanto intelligente quanto è stupida una scimmia 
o in alternativa = sei intelligente tanto quanto è stupida una scimmia.

4) Sei sincero quanto altruista = sei sincero tanto quanto altruista o sei tanto sincero tanto quanto altruista.

Vorrei solo sapere se sbaglio qualcosa nel mio ragionamento e cosa c'è da correggere.

Comment: «Qui non potrei dire "mangio tante quante pizze mangi tu", ma solo senza "tanto"»: questa frase non è in italiano né con né senza “tante”. Semmai, “mangio tante pizze quante ne mangi tu” oppure “mangio lo stesso numero di pizze che mangi tu” o, più ellitticamente, “mangio tante pizze quante te”. Nakamura, sono molto indiscreto se ti chiedo qual è la tua lingua madre?

Comment: Gli esempi 3 e 4 sono una semplice contrazione del più completo "sei tanto sincero quanto altruista". Non mi sembrano corrette senza "tanto" - anche se non posso dire di non averle mai sentite.

Answer (score -1):

`Tanto quanto` e `quanto` possono essere considerate due espressioni identiche in quanto entrambe esprimono il concetto di `esattamente la quantità richiesta` , motivo per cui fare speculazioni su il valore più o meno approssimato risulta futile

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Answer (score -1):

"**Quanto**" indica una quantità **indefinita**, "*nulla*".

Esempi:
1) Quanti soldi vuoi? = **NON** specifica la quantità, ma porge una domanda con "quanti" (agg., pro. ed avv.);
2) Quanto tempo hai a disposizione? = **NEANCHè** questa proposizione indica una quantità *ben precisa*, ma bensì rimane una domanda; porge la domanda quantitativa di "Quanto? Quanti? Quantità del tempo che hai a disposizione?", e così, **dunque**, "**Qual è la quantità del tempo che hai a disposizione?**".

Invece, "**tanto quanto**" indica **un'equivalenza** di quantità pari tra due o *più*, sempre **indefinite**;

Esempi:

1) Sei bello tanto quanto è bella mia nonna = Sei bello **UGUALE**, *QUANTITà INEFFETTIVA TALE A*'d un altra quantità **sempre non specificata**, *quanto* **è bella mia nonna**.
2) Hai tanta intelligenza tanto quanto ne ha Marco = Sei intelligente **TANTO QUANTO**, {*sempre solito discorso*}, **LO è** (*...*) *Marco*.

**DUNQUE**, *ricapitolando*;

Quanto = esprime una quantità indefinita, "quasi-nulla". Tanto quanto = esprime un'equivalenza di parità tra due o più elementi contenenti una o più quantità indefinita[e], "quantità ineffettiva tale a".

INFINE,

> quanto1
>   /quàn·to/
>   aggettivo, pronome e avverbio
>   1.
>   aggettivo e pronome
>   Opposto a quale, definisce la quantità invece della qualità, e al pari di quale ha valore interrogativo in proposizioni dirette e indirette, sia come aggettivo ( quanta pasta vuoi? - gli domandò quanta pasta voleva ) sia come pronome ( quanto ne vuoi? - gli fu chiesto quanto ne voleva - quanti ne abbiamo oggi?, che giorno è del mese?; questo è quanto, questo è tutto); accanto al valore interrogativo ammette anche quello esclamativo ( quanto pane! ; quanto lavora! ).
>   2.
>   avverbio
>   Come avverbio relativo equivale a ‘nella misura che’, ‘nella quantità che’.
>   "lavora quanto le forze gli consentono"
>
> quanto1
>   VOCABOLARIO ON LINE
>   quanto1 agg., pron., avv. e s. m. [lat. quantus agg., quantum [...] è bello, brutto, furbo q. mai; meno com. la locuz. tanto quanto (o tanto o quanto), un poco: fermati tanto o quanto, e guardami (Leopardi); o pressappoco, più o meno: «Avrai speso ...

Spero d'esserti stato d'aiuto! ;) :)

Comment: Potresti aggiungere le fonti delle tue citazioni? Grazie!

Comment: http://www.columbia.edu/itc/italian/resources/italiansite/GRAMMAR/COMPARATIVI%20E%20SUPERLATIVI/COMPARATIVI-REGOLE.htm CTRL+F -> tanto quanto/quanto (...); ric.